# Updating the modernizr from 2.x to 3.x

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I want to update a `Modernizr` and I don't know how to do this. In version 3.x there are other options.
The comment looks like this:

```
Modernizr 2.6.2 (Custom Build) | MIT & BSD
 * Build: http://modernizr.com/download/#-csstransforms3d-shiv-cssclasses-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-prefixes-domprefixes-load
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Modernizr` can be updated by generating a custom build on project site:

https://modernizr.com/download

This way the browser features that will be tested has to be selected.

Based on comments of provided existing v2 dist, the v3 equivalent would be:
https://modernizr.com/download?csstransforms3d-prefixed-prefixedcss-prefixedcssvalue-setclasses-shiv-testallprops-testprop-teststyles

Note: `Modernizr.load` is deprecated and removed from v3.

Comment: thank you ! it's exactly what I need it ! it works perfect !